# How to rotate labels according to an angle stored in a field in the attribute table?

Tags: qgis, python, labeling

I have a street name layer. I want to have the name of each street be fitted exactly into the street shape. There is a field in the attribute table which has a degree of rotation, which is the angle at which each label must be placed to be inside the street shape. How is it possible to do this with Python programming?

[image]

Comment: in screenshot  you can see i got this result manually

Comment: they are labels

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the rotation using python?

Comment: No actually i have this field in Attribute table. i need to do this process automatically by python .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field that contains the rotation angles, then it does not require python to define label rotation. You can use the the angles under a specific field as follows:

1. Go to `Layer properties -> Label -> Placement`
2. Under `Rotation` select the field that contains the rotation angles

[image]

The result will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: thank you but i Need to do that automatically by programming